# Текстбоксу присвоить значение char arr p[];

Tags: c++-cli

Как свойству Text в textbox присвоить значение массива char ?

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил сам ответил)

```
String^ sCertificate;
sCertificate = gcnew String(pcertificate);
```